# Help with node and field theming

Tags: theming

I am not particularly new to programming, but trying to theme how Drupal 7 outputs entity fields is giving me headaches. I think Drupal is great, but the documentation could be more organized and complete. I have sifted through a lot of material about this, but I'm still struggling to organize the bits and pieces of information into usable representation of how Drupal 7 treats and outputs field values.

This is an example output that one would like to obtain:

```
            <h1>#field value#</h1>                      // Suppose this is the node title
            <h2><a href="">#field value#</a></h2>       // Sub-title
            <div class="">                              // Attributes:
                <div>
                    <h3>
                        #field title#:
                    </h3>
                        #field value#
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3>
                        #field title#:
                    </h3>
                        #field value#
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3>
                        #field title#:
                    </h3>
                        #field value#
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3>
                        #field title#:
                    </h3>
                        <a href="">#field value#</a>    // e.g. Link to Taxonomy term page
                </div>
            </div>
```

`#field title#` and `#field value#`, represent where one would like Drupal to output the field titles and/or values submitted when creating entities/nodes.

The idea sounds straight-forward, but I find it to be immensely complicated in practice.

Some pitfalls I have encountered: Drupal makes presumptions, on how the field should be displayed, it gives it additional markup, which I have been unlucky in managing. When outputting through Panels the UI does not provide ways to separate field value and title. Am I under correct impression that I need separate template files or functions for all fields if I want the above structure?

Please shine some light on the matter. I bet many people would love to hear how more experienced developers approach these problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not a full answer, but you will need to use field template suggestions.

```
field--[type|name[--content-type]|content-type].tpl.php
base template: field.tpl.php
Theme hook suggestions are made based on these factors, listed from the most specific template to the least. Drupal will use the most specific template it finds:

field--field-name--content-type.tpl.php
field--content-type.tpl.php
field--field-name.tpl.php
field--field-type.tpl.php
Note that underscores in a Field's machine name are replaced by hyphens. Also remember to include "field-" in custom field names, e.g: field--field-phone.tpl.php.
```

The above is taken from https://drupal.org/node/1089656, so it for more information. As a side note, if there are a lot of fields being displayed or you are using a broad template, you would probably want to use a templating function instead, such an example can be seen in Bartik's `bartik_field__taxonomy_term_reference` ([Link here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/themes!bartik!template.php/function/bartik_field__taxonomy_term_reference/7)). The functions have a similar naming scheme to the .tpl.php files but with underscors instead of dashes.

**Update:**
You can cover all fields of a certain type with `field--field-type.tpl.php` (or `function theme_field__field_type()`), or all fields on a content type with `field--content-type.tpl.php` (or `function theme_field__content_type()`). You can then override these functions by using a more specific template (They have an order of preference). This can really cut down on the number of theming templates or functions required, essentially if a content type has 100 fields, you could theme them all with one template or function, if you so wished.

So you could use 1 function to theme all the fields on a content type if you wished, no matter their type or name. Alternatively you could field all fields of a certain type (eg. taxonomy_term_reference in the case of Bartik) no matter what their field names are or which content types they are on.

You could override one of these more general templates or functions with one which is more specific, from the `field.tpl.php` documentation above `field--field-type.tpl.php` will be overridden by any of the ones listed above it, if a relevant function exists. While `field--field-name--content-type.tpl.php` has the highest preference and will not be overridden by any of the others. This is just core behaviour, custom modules may alter the list, including adding new ones, which can lead to quite a powerful set of themeing functionality.

Templates are easier for themers to work with, I am told. I prefer functions because it avoids what may be a large number of includes in some cases.

Comment: Is writing custom functions for each field really a wise course of action in such cases? I hope there is a better solution.

Comment: @DominykasMostauskis You don't need to write a function, nor template for each field. As for it being wise, core already uses general functions, or templates which are run on every rendering of a field anyway, and as far as I am aware it will be more performant than modules which can be configured to accomplish a similar task. I have updated my answer with further information.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this in greater detail, you've cleared things up for me. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Drupal supports themeing fields and entities (typically groups of fields) together.

Other 3rd party contributed modules can help you get the output you want, and try to make it not a hassle. See the [Display Suite module](http://www.drupal.org/project/ds):

> Display Suite allows you to take full control over how your content is
>   displayed using a drag and drop interface. Arrange your nodes, views,
>   comments, user data etc. the way you want without having to work your
>   way through dozens of template files. A predefined list of layouts (D7
>   only) is available for even more drag and drop fun!

Also look at and the [Fences module](http://drupal.org/project/fences).

> Fences is a an easy-to-use tool to specify an HTML element for each
>   field. This element choice will propagate everywhere the field is
>   used, such as teasers, RSS feeds and Views. You don't have to keep
>   re-configuring the same HTML element over and over again every time
>   you display the field.
>
> Best of all, Fences provides leaner markup than Drupal 7 core! And can
>   get rid of the extraneous classes too!

Comment: I am now trying the Display Suite module. I always wrote it off as not useful with out trying it first, serves me right! It seems to remove quite a bit of hassle. At the same time I disabled Fences and HTML5 Tools modules, which I had already installed, and that too simplified matters quite a bit. I will notify as to what degree Display Suite solves these problems.

Comment: I have dropped Display Suite, in favor of using Panels with custom template functions for fields as suggested by Phizes. Display Suite was a close match to what I needed, but it lacked the contextual awareness of Panels that I needed.